# How to get rid of multiple whitespace AND account for a newline

Tags: python, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Say I have an input of `"Hello   my    name  is \\n Bill"`

```
my_str = ' '.join(my_str.split())
```

So this will join the letters and give me `"Hello my name is\nBill"` when I print it all on one line. What I want it to print is:

```
Hello my name is
Bill
```

to the terminal.

Comment: what? it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is you don't have a newline char, you have two *backslashes* and an `n` i.e the backslash is escaped so after splitting you need to do a replace:

```
In [10]: s = "Hello   my    name  is \\n Bill"

In [11]: print(" ".join(s.split()))
Hello my name is \n Bill

In [12]: print(" ".join(s.split()).replace("\\n","\n"))
Hello my name is 
 Bill
```

Or use *.decode("string_escape")*:

```
In [15]: s = "Hello   my    name  is \\n Bill"

In [16]: print" ".join(s.split())
Hello my name is \n Bill

In [17]: print(" ".join(s.split()).decode("string_escape"))
Hello my name is 
 Bill
```

As Kirby mentioned in a comment, if you are creating the strings don't escape the backslash, if the data is from another source use one of the methods above.

Comment: Might also want to mention that the input string could also just use one slash; if the OP is manually specifying the input, that may help clear things up.